# Firebase: How to retrieve data from two tables using id

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I come from an SQL background and recently started using Firebase for building an ionic shopping cart. This is the database schema:

[image: Shopping Cart Schema]

To retrieve a **user's** cart, i used the following

```
    var user_id="user1"; // Temporary initialised

    var refCart = new Firebase("https://testing.firebaseio.com/cart");
    var cart=$firebase(fireBaseData.refCart().child(user_id)).$asArray();
```

This gives the result:

```
item1 1
item2 2
item3 5
```

So tried using [foreach()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/foreach.html)

```
var refMenu = new Firebase("https://testing.firebaseio.com/menu");
refCart.child(user_id).on("value", function(snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

      var item_id = childSnapshot.name();
      var qty = childSnapshot.val();

      //var data= refMenu.child(item_id).val();  
      // val is not a function

      //var data= refMenu.child(item_id).exportval(); 
      // exportval is not a function

      //var data = $firebase (refMenu.child(item_id)). $asArray(); 
      // Give me an array of objects , ie attributes - OK! But what to do next ?

      //console.log("DATA",data );

      console.log("Item",item_id+" "+qty);

   });

});
```

How can i use **item_id** to retrieve **item details**.

Is it the correct way of doing data retrieval from multiple tables?

**Update:**

Using [on()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html) function , i managed to get the item attributes.

```
    refMenu.child(item_id).on("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log("Price",snapshot.val().price);
    });
```

But is there any better implementation for the same.

Is there any better ways to retrieve (from the server side) specific attributes for the item.
Like in SQL

```
SELECT name,price, ... from menu;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: `.on('event', callback)` method will call your callback every time the event is fired.

If you need to retrieve data from a reference once, you should use: `.once('event', callback)`

NOTE2: snapshot.val() will give you a JSON object that you can assign to a variable

I would do it this way:

```
refCart.child(user_id).on("value", function(snapshot) {

  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var item_id = childSnapshot.name();
    var qty = childSnapshot.val();

        refMenu.child(item_id).once("value", function(snapshot) {
          var item = snapshot.val()
          console.log(item.name +' '+ item.price)
        });

 });

});
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Hey @Devid, I wanted to retrieve the data from 2 tables, ie cart and menu. Is there any better alternative to this.

Comment: You don't have to do everything in 1 "query" like in SQL. It is a good solution to retrieve data from cart and then retrieve the data you need from menu. This is the firebase way of doing joins. 
From my understanding, the only thing you can improve is caching your "items" client side so that you don't need to query Firebase multiple times for the same item.

Comment: Thank you....But I wanted a better approach. As you can see, saving menu-items in cart would cause redundancy. And in this approach i almost need two arrays. I would like to know if NoSQL is good for such applications.

Comment: Yes, you are right this generates redundancy but it's fine. In my opinion, your solution is good and the way you structured your data makes it easy to retrieve them. But I'm not a guru :) 
I think is an interesting document to read: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html
Hope it helps

Comment: PS: 'You usually structure your data depending on how you want to retrieve them.'  this helped a guy with a SQL background understanding how to structure data. Maybe you can find it helpful ;)