# firebase structure many to many relationship

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I build an app for students and I wanna know how to implement many to many relationship.
in my structure, student study many courses , course has many students.
so if I want to display all the courses that student study I think to make node called "UserFavouriteCourses" then store as child the user key and his nodes child are all the keys of the courses like that
[image]

but how to implement the course has many students?
or maybe there is any other implementation I can do?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase or one of related answers that Stack Overflow provides to the right? All of those should give you a solid starting point.

Comment: Frank, if i want to get all the courses objects of the user so first I take the keys and then iterate of all the courses like firebase.ref().child('courses/course_key#number)? do you have an example?

Comment: Here's one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37911054

Comment: thanks, if you can see another issue I just asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760609/firebase-structure-college-db