# firebase structure college db

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I design my firebase structure and I'm not sure if that the right way.

Little information:

Each college has some departments.

Each departments has many courses.Courses can belong to several departments.
Each Course has some lessons. lesson can be belong to one course.

I have node of courses with all key courses and information
[image]

I have node of departments with all departments and informations.
I have node Course_Departments and Departments_courses
[image]

in addition I have courses_lectures and courses_lectures 
for display each course learn by some lecturers and each lecturers teach some courses.

so my questions are:
1.How I connect the lesson to these table for example? I want to find all the lessons of the course_key1 that lecture_key2 teach?
2. using with many tables in this way can be take many time to get the data? 
for UI I don't want to users to wait much for the data.

Comment: what have you tried? a little code can go a long way.

Comment: i still didn't code yet. just structure my db. I want to make relationship between courses to lessons to get for each course the lesson and the lecture that teach this lesson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your design, I think, you are on the right track.

I'll give some possible hints of what you can take care of. When designing the structure of a Firebase database design rules of non-relational databases should be kept in mind.

One of them is denormalization. Keep the hierarchy flat! That's an important performance factor for data change listeners since all subnodes are involved. That's what you've done so far.

Relationship of entities can be achied by using the keys. Exactly as you did it in the `Courses_Department` node. The built-in creation of keys should be used. They should be universally unique.

[Here's](https://youtu.be/ran_Ylug7AE) a good explanation when coming from relational databases.